# How do I get the contents of a Selenium Webelement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I've got a Selenium Webdriver on node.js and Firefox. I want to find and retrieve the outerHTML contents of a set of elements, but I'm failing at it.

Here's my code:

```
    let Elements = await driver.findElements(By.xpath('//img'));

    Elements.forEach(function(Element){
        console.log(Element);
    });
```

This produces a set of objects like:

> WebElement {
> driver_: Driver {
> session_: Promise { [Session] },
> executor_: Executor { customCommands_: [Map], log_: [Logger], w3c: true },
> fileDetector_: null,
> onQuit_: [Function: onQuit]
> },
> id_: Promise { 'b4519d34-d176-47e2-acf0-07d868e89a4e' }
> }

I've also tried:

```
    for(let Element of Elements) {
        text = await Element.innerHTML;
        console.log("Element: " + Element + " - Text:" + text);
    }
```

This gives me the results:

> Element: [object Object] - Text:undefined

And I've tried:

```
    Elements = promise.fullyResolved(Elements);

    console.log("Fullyresolved: " + Elements);

    Elements.forEach(function(Element){
        let text = Element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        console.log("Fullyresolved: " + text);
    });
```

Which gives me:

> Fullyresolved: [object Promise]

and a crash that Elements.forEach is not a function.

Any help appreciated!

TIA!

Comment: An image tag doesn't have innerHTML.  Seems like you'd want to get either the parent, or attributes within.  You can get the whole tag via outerHTML.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've tried it with innerHTML, outerHTML, getText etc. and it always produces the results above.